# Access Page Elements by Item Names

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In windows forms i access the all elements on page by these codes.(by names)

```
                            for (int ix = 1; ix < 31; ix++)
                        {
                            string name = string.Format("{0}{1}", "lbl", ix);
                            var nesne = this.Controls[name] as Label;
                            nesne.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("54C642");
                        }
```

How can i do on Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `FindByName`

```
var element = FindByName("myControlName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing Xamarin.Forms , use [x:Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xname-directive) .

##### Xaml

```
<object x:Name="XAMLNameValue".../>
```

##### Code behind

```
XAMLNameValue.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
```